# HTML text input - Prevent Windows 8 touch keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, accessibility

Is there a way to prevent the on-screen keyboard from popping up by default when a HTML text input field gets focus on a windows 8 touch screen pc?

The application in question is a barcode/rfid scanning web application.

It would be preferable if the user could also still pop up the on-screen keyboard manually if they need it.

Preferably a solution which avoids changing the global settings of the machine.

More Info: The text input field needs to be able to receive focus and accept keyboard input from the bar-code and rfid scanners attached to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#textbox1").attr("readonly", "readonly");
                or
$("#state").attr("readonly", true);
```

Thanks
AB

Comment: Thanks @ABertil. While I accept that this does 'technically' solve the issue of the on-screen keyboard popping up, it also means that the field can't accept input - which is required.

Comment: i didnt know that you need to accept input try changing disabled disabled to readonly..i will update the code..

Comment: Thanks for the help @ABertil, but setting the readonly attribute also prevents the text field from receiving focus or user input. I have updated the question to avoid ambiguity or confusion.

Comment: Then what you can do is like try setting $("#textbox1").attr("disabled", "true"); at first and on getting focus from the bar-code and rfid scanners attached to the terminal event set     $("#textbox1").attr("disabled", "false");..

Comment: Setting any html input element with a disabled or readonly attribute will prevent it from receiving focus (meaning the onfocus event will never fire) or input. Any value in the attribute ("true", "false", "please dont disable me"), or even no value at all will cause the element to be disabled by virtue of the fact that the attribute exists on the element.

Comment: I suppose you could always do something like this (a little kludgy):

1. Set attribute to read only
2. set focus
3. Remove read only attribute
4. Carry on...